# Jquery Ajax based search

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, search

I want to do the search using ajax jquery js, for that [I have taken this piece of code from here](http://www.developphp.com/view.php?tid=1143):-

Now i have some issues, I have this Javascript code:-

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
<!--
function searchuser(cv) {
    $("#SearchResult").html('<img src="loader.gif"/>').show();
    var url = "elements/search-user.php";
    $.post(url, {contentVar: cv} ,function(data) {
       $("#SearchResult").html(data).show();
    });
}
//-->
</script>
```

My Form:-

```
<label>
        <input onClick="generatenew();" type="radio" name="search_option" value="code" id="search_option_0">
        Customer Code</label></td>
      <td><label>
        <input onClick="generatenew();" type="radio" name="search_option" value="company" id="search_option_1">
        Customer Company</label></td>
      <td><label>
        <input onClick="generatenew();" type="radio" name="search_option" value="name" id="search_option_2">
        Customer Name</label></td>
      <td><label>
        <input onClick="generatenew();" type="radio" name="search_option" value="email" id="search_option_3">
        Customer Email</label>
```

This is my search textbox

```
<input type="text" name="searchuser_text" id="newInput" size="25" maxlength="25" class="inputbox MarginTop10">
```

This is my search button

```
<input onclick="javascript:searchuser('con1');" class="Button" name="search_user_submit" type="button" value="Search">
```

This is my Display Area :-

```
<div id="SearchResult">My default content for this page element when the page initially loads</div>
```

Now i want to know on click of button i am sending a data i.e. `con1`. I want to send two data to the `searchuser function`, one the selected option button value and the another one is the text in the `textbox`. After sending both the data to the function how will i get the data in the function? Do i need to change the `function searchuser(cv)` to `function searchuser(cv, cvtwo)`.

Also while the `$.post(url, {contentVar: cv} ,function(data)` is sending only one data to the php file, how can i send both the data i.e. `cv` and `cvtwo` to the php file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you can modify the search function to something like this

```
$("input[name='search_user_submit']").click(function(){
var cv = $('#newInput').val();
var cvtwo = //similar to above
var data = 'cv='+ cv + '&cvtwo='+cvtwo; // sending two variables
$("#myDiv").html('<img src="loader.gif"/>').show();
    var url = "elements/search-user.php";
    $.post(url, {contentVar: data} ,function(data) {
       $("#SearchResult").html(data).show();
    });

});
```

Comment: how i'll pass the values using the submit button?

Comment: var cv = $('#newInput').val(); // value from the search text field

similarly you can get values from the radio buttons and send them as parameters

Comment: Could you please write this for me on http://www.jsfiddle.net It would be of great help.

Comment: hey sorry for bothering again but in http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/ZELnk/1/show either values are not able to pass through the post or maybe be i am unable to understand what exactly values are being passed. Are you passing the select button value as `cvtwo` and textbox value as `cv`, because i am trying to fetch these values but unable to get anything, it gives me this error:- `Notice: Undefined index: cv`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9541/discussion-between-userd-and-abhilash-shukla)

Answer (score 2):

Don't  use inline functions, you can do it easily with jQuery's native bind functionality:

```
// Search when you click on submit
$(document).on('click', '.submit_button', function(){
   search('click_button');
});

// Search when you press enter
$(document).on('keypress', "#searchString", function(e){
    var c = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
    if(c == 13) {
        search('pressed_enter');
    }
});
```

You can therefore collect the button value and pass it through to your search function:

```
function search(button_value) {
    $("#myDiv").html('<img src="loader.gif"/>').show();
    $.post("elements/search-user.php", { search_value: $('#newInput').val(), button_value: button_value} ,function(data) {
       $("#SearchResult").html(data).show();
    });
}
```

What you're doing is send off the form with two $_POST variables: one is the search string you've inputted in to the search box (called `search_value`) and the other is the button value.

Comment: So my existing javascript needs to be replaced by the one you have given, and further i need to add the very second code. Could you please write this for me on http://jsfiddle.net It would be of great help.

Comment: could you please give me an insight that how can i get your answer implemented. Please.