# javascript based Jquery ajax function, unable to send post values

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, post

Hello this is code snippet which i get from [Jquery Ajax based search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9957841/jquery-ajax-based-search)

I am done with everything, just the problem is the following script may not be sending the `POST` variable and its values or may be i am not properly fetching it.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[name='search_user_submit']").click(function() {
        var cv = $('#newInput').val();
        var cvtwo = $('input[name="search_option"]:checked').val();
        var data = 'cv=' + cv + '&cvtwo=' + cvtwo; // sending two variables
        $("#SearchResult").html('<img src="../../involve/images/elements/loading.gif"/>').show();
        var url = "elements/search-user.php";
        $.post(url, {
            contentVar: data
        }, function(data) {
            $("#SearchResult").html(data).show();
        });

    });
});
});//]]>  
</script>
```

In php file i have the following code:-

```
if (isset($_POST['cv'])) 
{ 
// My Conditions 
} 
else 
{ 
// Show error 
}
```

And its showing error, This means everything is correct just the post is not working properly, maybe.

Do the `var data = 'cv=' + cv + '&cvtwo=' + cvtwo; // sending two variables` will do the needful or we need to do any modifications. I know questions like this really annoy people, but what should i do i am stuck up.. `@userD` has really helped me a lot just, this part is left.

Comment: Is the target URL in a different domain? If so, the server probably needs to support [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/).

Comment: No its not in a different domain, actually i am testing it on my localhost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using $.post instead of $.ajax, your call should be:

```
$.post(url, data, function(response) { 
  /// ...
});
```

data must be a Javascript object, like this:

```
data = { "cv" : cv, "cvtwo" : cvtwo };
```

Check Jquery's documentation for more info:

http://docs.jquery.com/API/1.1/AJAX#.24.post.28_url.2C_params.2C_callback_.29

Comment: [The data can be either an object or a string.](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

Comment: so `var data = 'cv=' + cv + '&cvtwo=' + cvtwo; // sending two variables` i need to replace with `data = { "cv" : cv, "cvtwo" : cvtwo };`

Comment: And to `$.post(url, {
            contentVar: data
        }, function(data) {
            $("#SearchResult").html(data).show();
        }` to `$.post(url, data, function(response) { 
  /// ...
});`